# Tomcat application not launching

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to launch an application in Tomcat 8 but when I launch it an HTTP 404 – Not Found page appears. I've tried several things but none of them worked. This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app
PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

<display-name>servletExample</display-name>
<description>
  A MVC application in java
</description>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Controlador</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Controlador</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Controlador</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Controlador</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And this is the log:

```
05-Mar-2018 16:10:32.802 GRAVE [http-nio-8080-exec-41] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement End event threw error
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagAttributeInfo.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ZLjava/lang/String;ZZLjava/lang/String;ZZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldRuleSet$Attribute.toTagAttributeInfo(TldRuleSet.java:273)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldRuleSet$TagAttributeRule.end(TldRuleSet.java:151)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1020)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLNSDTDValidator.endNamespaceScope(XMLNSDTDValidator.java:266)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:2005)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:879)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2967)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldParser.parse(TldParser.java:76)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.parseTld(TldScanner.java:279)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan(TldScanner.java:313)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:378)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:191)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5204)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1341)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:679)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:217)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:613)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I don't know where is the problem, I've reinstalled Tomcat and I don't know what to do now. I've read that the problem may be with conflicting jars or conflicting versions of the jdk but I don't know how to fix it. I aprreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your issue:

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagAttributeInfo.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ZLjava/lang/String;ZZLjava/lang/String;ZZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

You have a conflict with a JAR version.

See if you have an out-of-date JSTL JAR in your CLASSPATH and update it.